# Is there an alternative way to write a synchronized block in Java using CAS operations?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have two synchronized blocks that will be heavily accessed by two concurrent threads. I would like to reduce contention and context switches. Is there a way to accomplish that using CAS (CompareAndSet) operations on an `AtomicBoolean`?

Ex:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

// Thread A executing this
public final void methodA() {
   synchronized(lock) {
       ...
   }
}

// Thread B executing this
public final void methodB() {
    synchronized(lock) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` class as I don't think it makes a difference. I would like to use CAS.

Comment: Have you established (e.g. through profiling) that this is the actual bottleneck, or are you just guessing?

Comment: Yes this is a bottleneck. Even if it was not I would like to understand if there is an alternative through CAS. Thanks!

Comment: Richard - what kind of code is performed inside synchronized blocks? Just a simple operation on Boolean?

Comment: I personally am rather dubious about "I'd like to use this very specific solution for this vague underspecified problem; will it work?" sort of questions, but perhaps someone else will be able to help (or maybe you could provide more details about what the functions actually do).

Comment: Let me quote The Brian Goetz from another SE question on the same subject (CAS vs Locks): "The relative speed of the operations is largely a non-issue. What is relevant is the difference in scalability between lock-based and nonblocking algorithms. And if you're running on a 1 or 2 core system, stop thinking about such things.

Nonblocking algorithms generally scale better because they have shorter "critical sections" than lock-based algorithms."

Comment: @NPE I removed the world `faster` to calm you down.

Comment: What makes you think this is the bottleneck? If you're getting that from profiling in sampling mode (not instrumenting), you should be aware that nearly all samplers are strongly biased towards synchronization spots. See http://www-plan.cs.colorado.edu/klipto/mytkowicz-pldi10.pdf. You should (a) verify that the lock really is uncontended (e.g. by replaing with with `j.u.c.Lock` using `tryLock` and then (b) add instrumentation like `System.nanoTime` to confirm that it's really as slow as you think.

Comment: One thing you certainly can't decrease is contention because that is defined by the demand-side of the equation. Further, you can't know what technique will be used by the runtime for atomic monitor acquisition, but you can safely bet it will be a very optimized one. Trying to outsmart the JVM like this can possibly serve as a learning experience; otherwise it's an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the synchronized block by:

```
private final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();

while (!flag.compareAndSet(false, true));
try {
  //your code here
} finally {
  flag.set(false);
}
```

You should test both under your contention scenario to make sure that it does actually improve performance. CAS works best under small to mild contention.

As commented by @yshavit, [the JIT may already perform that sort of optimisation for you](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.3), so once again testing is important.

Comment: Is there any hard evidence demonstrating that this is (or can be under certain conditions) faster than a `synchronized` block?

Comment: `lock` (hence : `Object`) has no `compareAndSet` method, this code will not even compile. Please refrain from posting code which doesnt even compile.

Comment: Aye, the best multithreding is the absent one ;)

Comment: lock is just a name of the AtomicBoolean variable, chill :)

Comment: well in that case you're missing the declaration. Also : naming an `AtomicBoolean` "lock" doesnt make much sense - its like an instance of type `Cheese` being named `apple`.

Comment: @NPE CAS can perform better under mild contention but it is hard to say whether it will or won't perform better in general hence my recommendation to test.

Comment: @specalizt it is being used as a lock so the naming makes sense IMO.

Comment: @assylias: Perhaps, but I still think that offering at least some published benchmarks for the "can perform faster" part of the claim would significantly strengthen the answer.

Comment: um ... no. `AtomicBoolean` can not be used "as a lock", that doesnt make sense. An `AtomicBoolean` does ATOMIC MODIFICATION, hence strictly sequential - this is vastly different from locking

Comment: @NPE Chill bro. You are not helping, serious. :)

Comment: +1, but I would also add that if the lock can't be acquired, the thread will enter a busy-wait loop, thus discouraging the thread scheduler from putting other, more productive work on that core. It's only an advantage if the lock is almost never contended. I'm pretty sure (but not 100% sure) that HotSpot will find those spots anyway and turn them into a "busy loop for a few cycles, then park the thread and try to acquire a mutex," in which case this code is just a simpler version of what the JIT can do anyway.

Comment: @assylias I suggest changing the name from `lock` to `atomicBoolean` to make people happy here. People just need to relax.

Comment: well excuse my attention to detail - its my job and these nomenclature-breaches are what makes software unreadable ... i've already edited it.

Comment: @specializt Please change the name from `lock` to `atomicBoolean` and sleep well knowing that you haven't ruined someone's day by doing so.

Comment: Ah, found a citation that confirms my thoughts about HotSpot: `Adaptive spinning is an optimization technique where a two-phase spin-then-block strategy is used by threads attempting a contended synchronized enter operation.` ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.3)). So while this answer is correct in terms of functionality, I suspect that in most cases it will perform worse than a `synchronized` block.

Comment: @assylias while block needs to go inside the try catch too, or no?

Comment: @RichardBradley I don't think so, no. The spec of `AtomicBoolean::compareAndSet` says it returns `true` if successful. That means that if it throws an exception for any reason, it can't have been successful (since throwing an exception is incompatible with returning `true`). In that case, the lock was never acquired by this thread, and there's no need to unset it (in fact, you _shouldn't_, because that could mean you've released the lock that some other thread acquired).

Comment: Would someone care to comment on how/whether this differs from a synchronized block in terms of the visibility of variable changes made inside the block?

Comment: @dnault That's a good question. I recommend you open another question about that because here people will ask you: "Why do you think it is faster? Have you done your benchmarks?"

Comment: @dnault `compareAndSet` is equivalent to a volatile read + write. `set` is equivalent to a volatile read. So the visibility guarantees are the same as a synchronized block. Cf [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the actual scenario, a spinlock using CAS might or might not improve performance. If the code in the block is kinda long and time consuming, synchronized would still have to be your safest choice.

Can you try making the data immutable so that different threads would use different copies of data and no lock is needed?